# Git split and push to repo

Tags: split, tags, git-subtree, monorepo

I'm trying to build a monorepo setup like Symfony and trying to split a package from the monorepo https://github.com/symmono/symmono to it's own repo https://github.com/symmono/framework-bundle by using the splitsh lite https://github.com/splitsh/lite but can't get my head around the split and push commands.

When using splitsh to split, you retrieve an SHA1 that could be used to push the package to its own repo. When using git substree split the same SHA1 is retrieved, I believe this is the same technic. After recieving the SHA1, i can't find a way to push it to the new repo.

```
# splitsh, trying to split the master branch FrameworkBundle to it's own repo
git splitsh --prefix=packages/Symmono/Bundle/FrameworkBundle

# sha1
0 commits created, 0 commits traversed, in 0s
c5a195e73c6e2317f44fae252c1d2ae3beb323e7
```

Now i'm trying to push it to the framework-bundle repo

```
# at this moment the framework-bundle is an empty repo
# command 1 with respone
git push git@github.com:symmono/framework-bundle.git c5a195e73c6e2317f44fae252c1d2ae3beb323e7

fatal: c5a195e73c6e2317f44fae252c1d2ae3beb323e7 cannot be resolved to branch

# command 2 with respone
git push git@github.com:symmono/framework-bundle.git c5a195e73c6e2317f44fae252c1d2ae3beb323e7:master

error: unable to push to unqualified destination: master
The destination refspec neither matches an existing ref on the remote nor
begins with refs/, and we are unable to guess a prefix based on the source ref.
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@github.com:symmono/framework-bundle.git'
```

Branch split example

```
# branch split example
# when reading readme the --target flag shoud automatically create a branch for the split by passing a branch name, when running below command om main master monorepo
git splitsh --prefix=packages/Symmono/Bundle/FrameworkBundle --target=origin/0.1
0 commits created, 0 commits traversed, in 8ms
c5a195e73c6e2317f44fae252c1d2ae3beb323e7

# trying to push to branch
git push git@github.com:symmono/framework-bundle.git c5a195e73c6e2317f44fae252c1d2ae3beb323e7 0.1
error: src refspec 0.1 does not match any.
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@github.com:symmono/framework-bundle.git'
```

Questions:

1. Is there a command to see whats in that sha1?
2. How could i split and push the sha1 to an new repo?
3. Is it possible to split and push with tags?
4. Do you always split of the master branch, when or why to split a branch.
5. When working with tags, for example v2.1.2 should you work on branch 2.1 and consider the master branch as new released branch. In this example for v2.2?

**Update**

I've made it working to split an branch and tag.
On the monorepo i've created an branch,

```
git checkhout -b 0.1
```

made some changes. Now for splitting so that the package also get that branch i've used the follow command

```
# branch
git splitsh --prefix=packages/Symmono/Bundle/FrameworkBundle #5496113d8856bb00d11325153712a165c2071c3b

# push
git push git@github.com:symmono/framework-bundle.git 5496113d8856bb00d11325153712a165c2071c3b:refs/heads/0.1

# tag
git splitsh --prefix=packages/Symmono/Bundle/FrameworkBundle --target=tags/v0.1.2 # 5496113d8856bb00d11325153712a165c2071c3b

git push git@github.com:symmono/framework-bundle.git 5496113d8856bb00d11325153712a165c2071c3b:refs/tags/v0.1.2
```

Is this the correct way for splitting and pushing